# Is stick-deodorant an issue on shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, personal-hygiene

What kinds of deodorants are [mutar](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/591) on shabbat?

Which melacha might one violate if using stick deodorant?

Comment: resource http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Getting_Dressed_on_Shabbat#Deodorant

Comment: @Danno, thanks for the source; it doesn't specify why stick deodorant is a problem.

Comment: try this, page 3 http://www.jewishpathways.com/files/MandMs_-_Part_2__Memachaik3_Mesarteit3_Mechateich.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick deodorant had an issue with Memachek. Some (but not all) Poskim permit spray deodorant. Roll-on deodorant would be no problem.

Yet there are some who are strict and use only odorless deodorant because of creating an aroma (Mo'lid) unless there is at least some remnants of the odor from before Shabbos.

Comment: Hi yosef, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Moadim leSimcha!

Comment: "some remnants of the odor from before Shabbos" - what does this mean? Scented deodorant smells as soon as you open the can, and it smells like that all the time.

Comment: Some Rabbinic sources for your answer would improve it greatly.